# How do I fetch data from two tables as one row

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have two tables:

```
 _____________________________
| wp_post      | wp_postmeta |   
|______________|_____________|  
| ID           | meta_id     |
| post_title   | post_id     |
| post_content | meta_key    |
| guid         | meta_value  |
|______________|_____________|
```

The `wp_postmeta` table contains these rows:

```
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key        | meta_value
|---------|---------|-----------------|---------------
| 310     | 156     | level           | Blue
| 311     | 156     |_post_main_intro | Some text
```

The result I want is:

```
post_title, post_content, meta_value as color, meta_value as main_intro
```

I've tried different joins, but I'm not quite able to fix it.

This is as close as I get:

```
SELECT a.post_title, b.meta_key, b.meta_value
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.ID = b.post_id
WHERE b.meta_key = 'level'
```

But this does not allow me to fetch `_post_main_intro` data.

I'll be very happy if someone can push me in the right direction :)

**Update**
My current solution is this (and it works)

```
SELECT a.id, a.post_title, b.meta_value as color, c.meta_value as post_intro
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.ID = b.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON a.ID = c.post_id
WHERE b.meta_key = 'level'
AND  c.meta_key = '_post_main_intro'
```

Is this thew way to go?

Comment: Doesnt WHERE b.meta_key = '_post_main_intro' work..!

Comment: Are you looking for a pivot table? See this link  http://datacharmer.org/downloads/pivot_tables_mysql_5.pdf

Comment: @Sudhir He wants level and _post_main_intro in one row ^^

Comment: @Sudhir, I can change `level` to `_post_main_intro`, but then I'll only return rows having `_post_main_intro` and not `level`. See my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the meta table twice in your query:

```
SELECT a.post_title, b.meta_key, b.meta_value as level, c.meta_value as intro
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.ID = b.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON a.ID = c.post_id
WHERE b.meta_key = 'level'
AND c.meta_key = '_post_main_intro'
```

Edit: forgot to include third table in columns

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up using. I wasn't sure if this was the ebst solution. But it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT a.post_title, b.meta_key, b.meta_value
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON (a.ID = b.post_id)
WHERE b.meta_key = 'level' OR b.meta_key = '_post_main_intro'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have restricted the search to 'level'

```
WHERE b.meta_key = 'level'
```

Just remove that part, and it should give you all